# How to get InputStream in Rest-controller from file in request?

Tags: java, spring

I send file from frontend using fetch:

```
const invokeSavePayments = file => fetch("/rest/importPayments", {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "same-origin",
  body: file,
});
```

How to receive it (or better get InputStream) in spring-rest-controller?

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/importPayments"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, List<Payment>> importPayments() throws IOException {
        //need to get inputStream here
```

p.s.

I tried to use

```
public Map<String, List<Payment>> importPayments(@RequestParam("file") Object uploadedFileRef)
```

but there is error message
500 Internal Server Error

Current request is not a multipart request

> Stacktrace: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException:
>   Current request is not a multipart request

Comment: You are looking for a `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file`: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload. Make config from this example and then get stream: `file.getInputStream()`

Comment: you must also upload the file in multipart that is enctype multipart/form-data